# PHP LDAP Distinguish user from computer

Tags: php, active-directory

Is there a way to query with LDAP and leave out computers in the result?

There are users and computers inside the OU, and I only want to display the Users with their cn, title,address etc...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following to your LDAP filter `(!(objectClass=computer))`. This will exclude computer objects.

You can read more on LDAP filters in this [LDAP Filter Syntax](http://www.ldapexplorer.com/en/manual/109010000-ldap-filter-syntax.htm) article.

Comment: Thats great! weird I dind't find anything on google... Thanks for the article, thats really helpfull!

Comment: Or you could flip that around and explicitly say (objectClass=user)

Comment: @Rytmis this will not work. For example in Active Directory the computer object is also user object, so you need to explicitly specify that you don't want computer objects.

Comment: @ShaMan-H_Fel Well crap, I misremembered that then. Thanks for setting me straight. :)